# WalletSignTransactionError: Blockhash is invalid or can not be validated

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

it has been a while I am getting this error. This is only seen in my Brave Browser. Does anyone have idea on fixing this ?

This is caused on a function to send spl token using @Solana/web3.js.

I have fetched the recent blockhash from connection and added to the transaction.

Comment: Please share some example code so we can see what you're actually doing. The question as it does not provide enough context to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the respond @beeman. I think this issue is related to the problems with devnet that is going on now. I am waiting if the issue to be solved. Will include my queries further if this issue continues to happen

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because haven't heard from you in a 2 weeks, so I'm guessing your problem was indeed related to the devnet outage. Feel free to comment back with more details of not.